# How to make a servlet inaccessible to general users but accesible to other servlets?

Tags: java, servlets, web-applications

I've a servlet, say Servlet A that needs to dispatch control to another Servlet B, (Servlet B gets control dispatched to performs a delete operation based on a conditional check done in Servlet A). How do I ensure that only Servlet A can forward request to Servlet B? I don't want the user to figure out that Servlet B is used for user deletion and invoke it directly.

When I think about it, I can see that some of you may say, why have Servlet B do just delete, why can't it do conditional check that is being done in Servlet A and then do the delete based on what the condition evaluates to. Well, this delete operation could be made public in the future and it will probably have role based authorization. For now, I just want it to exist, but unavailable for users of the application to use directly.

Comment: Authentication and authorization.

Comment: Authentication and authorization doesn't have to be hard. Just pass around (request attributes) a token or marker that the second servlet will accept or deny (ex. lack of token).

Comment: a filter should do then for adding that request attribute?

Comment: It could, but is it the `Servlet` or a `Filter` that has the knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just not use a servlet for B and instead just have a method in the object that does the deletes but isn't accessible publicly?  Then if you decide to make it public later, you can implement a servlet that invokes it directly.  You shouldn't have business logic in your servlets anyhow, it's just part of the presentation layer, right?